# Reading files from outside the class path in Intellij

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea

I am trying to read a file given its path that may not be inside the class path of the current project; the project has been exported as a separate .jar file and should be run from any directory it is located in. The code for reading the file is:

```
try {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

    String strLine;

    while ((strLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    // read file
    bufferedReader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Err couldn't find " + inputMailFile);
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106892/intellij-idea-problem-with-text-file-impossible-to-read) question only refers to the case when a file is being read from the current working directory.

How can I read a file given only its path?

`inputFile` is a string to the file path. For example:

```
C:\\Users\\user\\file.txt
```

Comment: Just provide the absolute path to the file, not a relative path.

Comment: If you know the absolute file path why can't ?

Comment: I am using the absolute path but I am getting file not found exception.

Comment: The code is working. Have you done a `e.printStackTrace()` to check on the specify error?